# reactjs-how to get axios response data from parant component to a child component

Tags: reactjs, axios

I've defined a component for requesting data from server and getting the result by axios and I want to use that component to whole of my app for sending requests,I'm going to pass an api link and body to that component and get response from that and I must pass result to my child component!
imagine use clicks on login button,child component sends username and password to parent component(axios component) and will get response data from that
I want to show spinner while getting the data it's important to me!
thanks to everybody!

Comment: Please share the code too.

Comment: Lightweight solution would be to use the React [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). A provider component wraps the app tree and any component needing access can subscribe (consume) to the context. Many global app state solutions are built on the context API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a functional components, then it's a good place to use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)
It can be something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useRequest = () => {

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const yourAxiosRequest = () => {
    //implementation of your axios request
  }

  const requestHandler = async (url, data) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
  
    try {
      await const response = yourAxiosRequest({
        url,
        data,
        method: 'POST',
      });
      setData(response.data);
    } catch (e) {
      setIsError(true);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }

  return {
    isError,
    isLoading,
    data,
    requestHandler
  };
};
```

and then in your components you can use it like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRequest } from 'common/useRequest';

//your component code

const { isLoading, isError, data, requestHandler } = useRequest();
const clickHandler = (data) => requestHandler(url, data);

//your component code
```

Comment: I'm sending request to parent like this and I got no thing in first click but when clicked one more time I,m getting result,I can't check loading state for showing spinner because it is false until I click again import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {MyRequest} from '../../HttpRequest/ReqToServer'

export default function Welcome(){
    const { isLoading, isError, data, requestHandler } = MyRequest();
    const clickHandler = (data) => requestHandler('http://localhost/ankavita/user/1/detail');
return (
    <button onClick={()=>clickHandler(1)}>Submit  </button>
    
)
}

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain this using the example you have given, i.e login and loading spinner.
It is ideal for you to use a state management library like redux. It will be the one responsible to handle the data for you. From what I can make from your question, it is called data-binding.

Please check out this for further insight: [React Redux getting started](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react)